# Does UNION ALL return an array?

Tags: php, sql

I have a sql statement that is a union of several queries.

```
"SELECT a, b, c, 'd' as type FROM x WHERE id = $id UNION ALL
 SELECT a, b, c, 'e' as type FROM y WHERE id = $id UNION ALL
 SELECT a, b, c, 'f' as type FROM z WHERE id = $id ORDER BY a DESC LIMIT 10";
```

I try to iterate through the results and get 'a' value for each row but can't make it to work.

```
for($i =  0 ;  $i <  mysql_num_rows($result) ; $i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo($row['a']);
}
```

I know it is a silly question but I got stuck.
Any ideas please?
Thanks!

Comment: check if `var_dump($row instanceof  Traversable);` is true or not!

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I changed the query to this and it worked:

```
"SELECT a as A, b as B, c as C, 'd' as type FROM x WHERE id = $id UNION ALL
 SELECT a as A, b as B, c as C, 'e' as type FROM y WHERE id = $id UNION ALL
 SELECT a as A, b as B, c as C, 'f' as type FROM z WHERE id = $id ORDER BY a DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy/paste your code or retype it?

```
$row = mysql\_fetch\_assoc($**g**uery);
```

Come to think of it, you should be calling `mysql\_fetch\_assoc` on a result handle, not a query.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it on a result handle, but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Bad practice, Should never call a function in a for loop this will cause performance issues.

```
for($i =  0 ;  $i <  mysql_num_rows($result) ; $i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo($row['a']);
}
```

Also do you want to fetch the associate array in the loop? this will execute every time as well?

Good Practice

```
$countRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($i=0; $i<$countRows; $i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "Row: ".$row['a']."<br />";
}
```

or

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
   echo "Key: ".$key." Value: ".$value."<br />";
}
```

or

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo "Row: ".$row['a'] . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer the actual question ("Does UNION ALL return an array?").

No, `union [all]` doesn't *return arrays*, it is used to concatenate resultsets. If it is used in the `union all` form, it makes sure, that all the duplicate rows in the resulting resultset are preserved.

That's `all` there is to it.